# Java SocketException after trying to send and receive data on the same socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, socketexception

I am working on a project in Java and I am trying to send an object from the client to the server and then waiting for a String response, but I get SocketException with the message "Socket is closed" on server at the line where I'm creating the DataOutputStream and SocketException with the message "Socket closed" on client at the line where I called the readUTF method.

Client error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.ensureOpenAndConnected(NioSocketImpl.java:165)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.beginRead(NioSocketImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:299)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:976)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:971)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:595)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:570)
    at client.Client.main(Client.java:26)
```

Server error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:1008)
    at server.Server.handleRequest(Server.java:83)
    at server.Server.run(Server.java:74)
    at server.Server.main(Server.java:63)
```

Client code:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket soc = new Socket("localhost", 8080);

            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());

            Planification p = new Planification(0, "Alex", "5070921647382", LocalDate.now(), 2, 1, LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 15), LocalTime.of(12, 0, 0));
            out.writeObject(p);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            System.out.println(in.readUTF()); //ERROR HERE
            in.close();

            soc.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
private void run() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8080);
    System.out.println("Server started on port 8080");
    while (true) {
        final Socket connection = socket.accept();
        this.handleRequest(connection);
        connection.close();
    }
}

private void handleRequest(Socket connection) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Future<String> result = executorService.submit(new ServiceCallable(this.locationsRepository, this.paymentsRepository, this.planificationsRepository, this.treatmentsRepository, connection));
    String res = result.get();
    System.out.println(res);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); //ERROR HERE
    out.writeUTF(res);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Call method from the ServiceCallable class:

```
public synchronized String call() throws Exception {
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
    objectInputStream.close();
        
    ...
    Some verifications and return of the String message
    ...
}
```

Any help is appreciated...

**Edit:**
I changed the handleRequest method so that I dont give the connection to ServiceCallable but instead give the object read and changed the call method too (because i dont have the connection anymore) and I still have the same errors.

```
private void handleRequest(Socket connection) throws ... {
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    Object command = objectInputStream.readObject();
    objectInputStream.close();

    Future<String> result = executorService.submit(new ServiceCallable(command, ...));
    String res = result.get();
    System.out.println(res);

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.writeUTF(res);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

```
public synchronized String call() throws Exception {
    ...
    Some verifications and return of the String message
    ...
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like as soon as you connect, the server writes a message to the client and then immediately closes the connection. So how could the client then write to the server?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to put the code from the Callable that I gave to the executor service, I edited the question now. In the call method I read the sent object from the client.

Comment: Generally speaking, the correct design of the protocol prevents this problem. Each side needs to know what to expect before closing in an orderly way.

Comment: So how do i solve this

Comment: For example close when the client has sent "goodbye"

Comment: I added an edit to the question at the end with what I tried

Comment: Don't close *any* stream (in addtion obvs. to the connection) until your protocol says all is done

Comment: Wow... that was really the problem, I didnt even think of that. Im so happy that it works now, thank you so much!